# BIlling system - Programming

Tags: java, ruby, math

I require some input on the below logic.

It is kind of billing system takes the input and has a value associated with it.

```
A = 2 , 3A = 5
B = 3
C = 1 , 4C = 3
```

My code , should be such that take ABCCBAACCA , output should be value which is 16.

My solution as of now, I m thinking to count every element in the string, and them mod(modulus) by 3 for A , 4 for C (as in the above case, no need in case of B) every element in order to get the result.

I'm confused what data structure I should be using in order to implement such system.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't ask homework questions here???

Comment: Yeah , it is not a home question. It is for a programming logic, that I m tried to implement at my workplace. Well scanning the string all at once, then compute the price can be solution. But i want to make it scable and was looking is it possible to make it fast than that.

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting your output for `ABCCBAACCA`. You have four As, two Bs, and four Cs. Shouldn't the result then be 4*2 + 2*3 + 4*1 = 18? And what does `3A = 5` mean? Does it mean if the strings have three As, they should total to 5 instead of the usual 6? In which case `ABCCBAACCA` would evaluate to 5+2+6+3 = 16.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I interpreted incorrectly, it , for 3A the value should be 5 , but for 4A , it should be 3A + A, therefore for ABCCBAACCA it is 3A + A + B + B + 4C = 5 + 2 + 3 + 3 + + 3 = 16.

Comment: so four As cost `5+2`, two Bs cost `6`, and four Cs cost `3`. `5+2+6+3` = 16. Why, then, do you say `ABCCBAACCA` costs 13?

Comment: Why is this tagged both Java & Ruby? Which are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudocode I believe it would be:

Count all A's, B's and C's

1. Divide A's by 3 and multiply by 5
2. Modulo A's by 3 and multiply by 2
3. Multiply B's by 3
4. Divide C's by 4 and multiply by 3
5. Modulo C's by 4

Sum the 5 results.

In Ruby it could like something like this:

```
input = "ABCCBAACCA"
letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
total = 0

def score(letter,count)
  if letter == "A"
    ((count/3)*5)+((count%3)*2)
  elsif letter == "B"  
    count*3
  else letter == "C"  
    ((count/4)*3)+(count%4)
  end  
end 

letters.each do |letter|   
  puts "#{letter}: #{score(letter, input.count(letter))}"
  total += score(letter, input.count(letter))
end

puts "Total: #{total}"
```

Which produces:

```
A: 7
B: 6
C: 3
Total: 16
```

Comment: I like your idea of counting all As, Bs, and Cs, since the order of the letters in the string doesn't seem to matter. But the rest of your pseudocode is hard to read. Can you rewrite it using mathematical symbols, `/, *, %, +`, and parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the modulus operator won't help you since you will be getting 0 everytime is a multiple of 3 or 5, depending the letter you are evaluating (if thats what you trying to describe, sorry if i got it wrong).

I believe the easiest way is scanning the string and just adding the values.

When you encounter a third A you just add 1, instead of 2 (because you have to subtract 4, then add 5)
Similarly with C, you just add 0, instead of 1, when you encounter the fourth C.

You need 2 additional variables to keep the instances of A and C, and yes, you can use modulus operator to know if you just arrived to a multiple where you have to add either 1 or 0, depending the case.

Hope this helps a bit.

EDIT:
Here, I did a quick implementation.  Feel free to optimize it if you really need it ;)

```
    String value = "ABCCBAACCA";
    int numA =0;
    int numC =0;
    int endResult = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < value.length(); x++)
    {
        if (value.charAt(x) =='A')
        {
            numA = numA +1;

           endResult = endResult + ((numA%3 == 0)?1:2);
        }
        else if (value.charAt(x) =='B')
        {
            endResult = endResult +3;
        }
        else if (value.charAt(x) =='C')
        {
            numC = numC +1;
            endResult = endResult + ((numC%4 == 0)?0:1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(endResult);  //16 as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would start with something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // FIXME
    String inputString = null;

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (Character c : inputString.toCharArray()) {
        map = countCharacters(map, c);
    }
}

private static Map<Character, Integer> countCharacters(Map<Character, Integer> map,
        Character charatcer) {
    map.put(charatcer,
            (map.get(charatcer) != null) ? map.get(charatcer) + 1 : 
                Integer.valueOf(1));

    return map;
}
```

and then introduce @**vlasits** steps from second to 5th, as this code above is first step in his pseudocode. It counts all characters in your string by making map of "character" : "its Occurences", if there was no such a character before, it puts 1 to the map.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CharBucket
  attr_accessor :count

  def initialize(thresholds)
    @thresholds = thresholds
    @count = 0
  end

  def total
    @thresholds.inject([0, @count]) do |sum_left, a|
      sum = sum_left[0]
      left = sum_left[1]
      sum += (left / a[0]) * a[1]
      left %= a[0]
      [sum, left]
    end[0]
  end
end

a = CharBucket.new({3 => 5, 1 => 2})
b = CharBucket.new({1 => 3})
c = CharBucket.new({4 => 3, 1 => 1})
buckets = {'A' => a, 'B' => b, 'C' => c}

"ABCCBAACCA".each_char{|c| buckets[c].count += 1 }
total = buckets.values.inject(0){|sum, b| sum += b.total} # => 16
```

Comment: I really like this answer.  Elegant.